Best way to activate DEV mode on a webapp
I have a webapp (SPA) that can work in a web browser along with my iOS and Android app webviews. I need a way to activate what I call a DEV or DEBUG mode, in order to:

Target another API (test API for example or plug the test webapp to the prod API)
Change the log level and send logs to a server so I can see what is going on internally
Display extra functionality such as experimental features
I could direct a calling customer to activate those features and help him debug his app
Probably more to come

What I proposed my boss is to have some kind of a cheat code, much like the 8 taps on the version number to activate debug mode on Android. You would enter "SECRET_CODE" in the login field and triple click on login and it would show a menu to activate those things for example. He doesn't like the idea too much citing security concerns.
Is my idea so dumb? Is there best practices around this kind of stuff?
Edit
The question is not about how to do it, but about whether it's a good or bad idea to do it in the client side with a cheat code. Answers have proposed a server side activation of the debug mode, which doesn't help in many scenarios
As stated I need this to be able to:

Enabling remote logging so I can see the DEBUG log of the webapp running on my customer phone/PC. This would leak sensitive data so before asking a user to turn it on, I would disclaim the security implications. Being able to activate it server side would mean than an attacker could enable DEBUG mode on ALL my customers leaking sensitive data.
Configure the app to target another API. This is more of development need. Enabling the prod app to target my dev API server side might prove to be a challenge. I'd need to target a specific instance of the app, which after thinking might just be easier on the client side.
Enabling a feature that is not released yet. If it's in the non authenticated part of the app, server side is a no go.


After more research on this, I concluded that there was no way to achieve this securely on the web completely client side without some help from the server. Even native apps use server side encryption and authentication of some kind (Adobe XD for example does this because of possible security vulnerability due to reverse engineering) to release some beta features to some clients. For added security, they release the application in beta mode for testing before releasing the actual production ready software. If security is paramount, your approach needs thinking it through properly.

If you're happy to limit it behind auth
The best thing to do here would be provide DEV/DEBUG mode to authenticated users and feature flag it. The feature flags here would be:

Frontend feature flag (presumably a toggle in the header)
Backend feature flag - toggle DEBUG access to specific users

Subdomains blocked by auth (e.g. dev.your-webapp.com) are a pretty common way to deal with releases, and may be what you want to use here, though shouldn't really be shared with end users.
If you don't want to limit it behind auth (proceed with caution)
If you don't want to allow access based on account/auth, your problem is a little more complicated.
If you're absolutely set on being able to access some debug mode via a 'cheat code', you should at the least lock this down to expected devices. You could whitelist IPs, device fingerprints, limit access to single sessions, time limit, etc. I'd avoid this personally. Without knowing the inner details of what you'd be exposing, your boss is likely correct in his security concerns.
Customers aren't very good debuggers
Asking a customer to debug their own app is best avoided. It's a poor user experience, and the person you're interacting with is unlikely to have the technical knowledge to help with debugging much. Log errors which users encounter and debug it on your end wherever possible.

Thanks for your answer. I know customers aren't good with debugging, hence my need to be able to give them simple instructions to enable verbose logging to my server. That way I can debug for them. Whitelisting IPs would defeat the purpose of being able to help a random customer calling customer service. Also, verbose logging could leak private data from the customer (passwords, wifi networks), so I don't want to be able to activate this from the server. That would be a major security issue. I want the user to act on it so that it's their informed choice.

I edited the question to answer your post.


Best way to activate DEV mode on a webapp

On NodeJS this is quite easy to achieve using environment variables for example:
function debug(msg) {
  if ("production" !== process.env.VAR /*[1]*/)
    console.log(msg);
}
export default debug;
Now all calls to debug() will only actually log if the app is built in DEBUG mode.
This is more secure than the proposed solution which was rightfully declined because DEBUG mode is not something a user should be able to activate.

Edit 1:
If you have an app running on the browser and you want to allow users enable DEBUG mode by themselves, that is a dangerous proposition. There are security considerations you have to keep in mind [2] but nonetheless, you can easily achieve this.
In a part of the app —possibly developer section— you can have a button that when quadruple-clicked can turn on a switch like so:
window.mode = (window.mode === "debug") ? "production" : "debug"; /*[3]*/
Now we will use the window.mode value to determine what mode we are working in:
function debug(msg) {
  if ("production" !== window.mode)
    console.log(msg);
};
Edit 2:

The question is not about how to do it, but about whether it's a good or bad idea to do it in the client side with a cheat code.

This draws the question to an opinion based point. I refuse to give a subjective answer but rather an objective one.
Whatever you do, do not write implementation details in DEBUG code and then allow clients to turn it on. You will be exposed to attacks.

[1] VAR is your desired environment variable used to check DEBUG mode vs PROD mode.
[2] These security considerations depends somewhat on what code there is surrounded by DEBUG conditional. As an amateur black hat hacker, the first advantage I will gain lies in what information wasn’t properly cleaned up after development. Worse if I can easily gain access to this simply through a switch the dev team left for me to turn on.
[3] The switch relies on undefined to choose initial value as "debug" which aligns with expectation.

My app is running in a browser... How would this help me? I cannot set an environment variable on my customer's iPhone ... And even if I could, I would not be able to read it.

In NodeJS you can. Otherwise check what your framework offers. If this is VannillaJS then global variables will do. It is the same mechanism but it boils down to technology at hand.

It's code running in a browser I'm interested in enabling debug for, not in NodeJS. There is no NodeJS on my customer's phones. This has nothing to do with server side.

”server side”? @pieroxy I’m sorry for the confusion but NodeJS is a JavaScript runtime environment. It can be used to write JavaScript code that can be well tested to run on a browser. Many frameworks rely on it’s versatility for this. Examples include: ReactJS, VueJS e.t.c. I made edits to suit your specific use case which I wasn’t aware of at first.

Your edit clarifies. But you say there are security concerns and move on to describe something I already know. My original question if about the security concerns. I am clarifying in my question.

Since a dev mode may be unsecure, some experimental code may be in there to be tested out you will need to make sure that no-one should have access to it except for users whom you want to be able to test.
You could have a setting for users to determine which mode will they use and have a list of users whom are set to dev users. If so, then you can provide a dev and a prod user to your boss, who will be able to securely log in with the user of his choice and proceed with testing. But this solution would only work for logged-in features.
A way better way to deal with this is to have two copies of the repository, a prod and a test copy and hide the test copy behind a firewall. They would be reachable from two different URLs and your boss would simply load the URL of his choice and this solution would include features reachable without authentication to be reachable too.
You have wondered why your suggested solution is unsafe. The reason is that any system is as secure as its weakest link. Let me provide you an example:
let's suppose that your boss hires a disloyal person and this disloyal person finds out how one can switch between modes. Due to the disloyal person's shortcomings, he is fired. So he wants a revenge. How would you deprive him from accessing your app in dev mode? With your suggested solution you are unable to do so. Because an extremely un-secure and well-known text along with some actions allow one in to dev mode.
So you get an urgent task from your boss, who might have been unwise to fire the disloyal person before realizing the security problem and you will need to change this feature, brief everyone about the new way to tap the mode of the app, but by the time you even start implementing this, it might already be late.
Whereas, if you have a list of users who are allowed to pass the VPN, then you just remove the users of your malicious ex-colleague.
In general terms you always need to restrict giving rights to the absolute necessities, so no-one is not even allowed to do things they do not need to do. Hence, if you allow your users to switch between dev and prod mode and you rely on the lack of knowledge of your end-users about this trick, then sooner or later you will end up having a malicious user figuring it out in some manner and doing harm.
Never create weak spots on your security relying on the lack of knowledge of hackers about it, because hackers are good in figuring out things and it's best to guarantee that they are not able to exploit those weaknesses even if they figure it out. I know, one could counter-argue that hackers may figure out a password. Which is true, but it's way more difficult a task than to figure out a hidden feature. Especially if they have/had access to the source-code, as in open-source environments.

Whether it's the client or the server that originate the debug mode, it's always the client that activates it. Anyone can install a proxy and MITM requests to his own app to simulate a server activating the debug mode. If the webapp has a DEBUG mode, anyone skilled enough can activate it. Now the security issue lies in what can be done once activated, not on the way to activate it. Logging is innocuous, plugging into another API is possible for everyone with a proxy anyways, experimental features should not be rolled out unless security has vetted them.

@pieroxy you did not understand the main point of the answer, that is, that my suggestion, even my recommendation is to have two copies of your repository, the first being prod available to the general public and the second being the dev/debug mode which is in debug mode and which could only be reached via VPN/firewall, so it would only be available for active team members. Independently of how skilled the users are.

Thanks for the clarification. How could I direct a customer to the debug version of the repository then ?

@pieroxy you would have two copies of it and you would reach the debug version by reaching out to URL1 and the prod version by reaching out to URL2. For URL1, since it's more volatile, you would create a VPN/firewall whatever rule to restrict access for those who should never access it and the other URL would be reachable by any normal customer. So your boss would know to reach URL1 when he wants to test in dev mode and URL2 otherwise. You would have a single project being versioned and an unversioned settings file and the two copies would mainly differ on their mode setting.

@pieroxy happy to help. If this answer helped you, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

I would say this requires a configuration management design. Here is how I would do it.
CONFIGURATION OBJECT
I would start with an object such as this:
export AppConfiguration {
  apiBaseUrl: string:
  logLevel: number;
  useExperimental: boolean;
}

GET THE CONFIGURATION
In code I would default the settings to production values. At runtime, if the web origin is not the production one your SPA can download a file like config.json from its web host, containing environment specific values, eg for the API base URL. This ensures that all environments default to the correct values.
APPLY OVERRIDES
To update the log level, activate experimental features, or switch environments, the web UI should provide a settings screen that is a little hidden away.
I would use a menu option to invoke the screen, but that could be done according to your preferences. Some values might be disabled based on whether the user is authenticated or the value of user attributes such as a role. The screen might also have a reset button that restores default values.
CONFIGURATION PERSISTENCE
You can design this however you like:

Configuration is reset when you reload the page
Configuration is saved in session storage and maintained if the user reloads the page
Configuration is saved in local storage and maintained if the user closes and reopens the browser

EXTENSIBILITY
Such a design should cope with any additional settings you want to add in future.
SECURITY
Such a design should have no security weaknesses. The configuration object itself should contain no secrets, so that it is safe to show to the user, download from a server or store in the browser.
If you change the API base URL to point to a different stage of your deployment pipeline, that alone should not grant access. Instead, the user should also need to have a valid user account for that stage, so that the backend enforces security.
Any data shown, eg in verbose logs, should only include information that the user has access to in their UI session. The user should never gain access to unauthorized data
or be able to elevate their privileges, eg to access data for other users.
I would also aim to mask any sensitive data that you include, at any log level. This should include personal data like names and emails.
SUMMARY
This would be my approach:

Represent configuration as an object and allow parts of it to be overridden per environment or by users

Enable user control in the frontend but make all security decisions in backend components



I've done something similar in a hybrid mobile app that runs a React app in the native WebView.
Is it a good idea? I guess that depends on what you're exposing but probably not.
Perhaps you could set some flag on the backend that unlocks some debug features? Like on the user object or on the token response.
